# Setting Up Database Connection with Sequelize & PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, database-connection, node-postgres

I am wondering if anyone in the community is able to help me understand a bit more about the connection between PostgreSQL and Sequelize through node-Postgres. I understand that I install Sequelize, that if I am using someone of the SQL flavors that I need to install their dependencies in order for the connection from a database interface to connect to the files in the application I am building. The question I have is when I use node-Postgres 'POOL' to connection is it the same as using the Sequelize instance? Or is it that node-Postgres is the actual part of the connection and Sequelize is the way I interact with the database in my file applications? Please help me understand. I appreciate all the feedback I can get. If a visualization would help then here is it:

```
export const pool = new Pool({
   database: 'postgres',
   port: 5432,
   host: process.env.HOST,
   user: process.env.USER_NAME,
   password: process.env.DB_PASS
});

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres', process.env.USER_NAME, process.env.DB_PASS, {
   host: process.env.HOST,
   dialect: 'postgres'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood Sequelize uses `pg` package when you set dialect: 'postgres'.
So if you wish to use `connection pool` you can indicate this like:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */, {
  // ...
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

I suppose Sequelize uses `Pool` object from `pg` to achieve a `connection pool`.